# Where does the meta content live in the MVC?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, model-view-controller

I've been thinking about meta content in MVC, specifically the page title and the meta description (which is useful for guiding the snippet Google shows on your search result).

I can't come to a firm decision about where this should live though. There's often a little bit of logic around it depending (for a UGC application) on how readers have interacted with the content.

I can't decide whether this meta content is better constructed in the view layer or the controller. It almost certainly doesn't live in the model since it is specific to a particular view of the data however while my first instinct was to put it in the view I feel that it might be better abstracted.

I'm interested in what approach other people have taken.

Comment: for meta, i assume you are referring to html tag, have you seen appliation.html.haml/erb? i just fix the css/ views for things like page title

Comment: You're right, it's not an easy decision. I usually put this in helpers.

Comment: Views should be as stupid as possible (IMO). It likely depends on the meta-data, however; some may very well live in the model, but more likely belongs at the controller level, even if it's not (always) in the controller itself.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Meta content is typically set using helpers, `content_for` and `yield`.

For instance:

```
# app/helpers/application_helper.rb
def title(title)
  content_for :title, title
end

def description(description)
  content_for :description, description
end

# app/views/layouts/application.html.erb
<title>My app <%= yield :title %></title>
<meta name="description"><%= yield :description %></meta>

# app/views/some_controller/some_action.html.erb
<%
title @an_instance.an_attribute # or whatever you want by the way
description @an_instance.another_attribute
%>
```

If you intend to do [streaming](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionController/Streaming.html), you should use `provide` instead of `content_for` in your helpers.

Never ever put an instance variable in your controller that is used for meta content (such as `@title = 'blabla'; @description = 'blablabla'`)

Here are some resources that do the same (list non-exhaustive):

- [BUILDING BULLETPROOF VIEWS](http://en.oreilly.com/rails2011/public/schedule/detail/19279) (the slides are downloadable)
- [Rails Best Practices](http://www.codeschool.com/courses/rails-best-practices) (commercial)